# mpicc takes long time in alpine container

Tags: docker, gcc, compilation, mpi, c-preprocessor

I have a docker container running `alpine:latest` in which I installed `build-base, openmpi, openmpi-dev,..` and basically everything works fine, except when I run

`mpicc -v -time=time_out -o /root/cloud/test /root/cloud/mpi_hello_world.c`

The preprocessing stage [`-E`] takes ~90sec for the first time. Second time is less than a second. I attached the `-v` option to `mpicc`below. Please note that the produced executable runs fine and fast with all my nodes/slots.

What I tried to fix this issue was looking at the verbose output of `mpicc -v [...]` and between

```
...
End of search list.
<---- Between these two lines we spend ~85sec estimated ---->
GNU C17 (Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027) version 10.3.1 20211027 (x86_64-alpine-linux-musl)
...
```

we loose time. I have a hunch, that `gcc` searches for something which it eventually finds. But I dont know what it is.

Can please someone help me identify the missing element?

Please see the output of the `mpicc -v [...]` command:

```
bash-5.1# mpicc -v -time=time_out -o /root/cloud/test /root/cloud/mpi_hello_world.c | tee /root/myFiles/mpicc_verbose 
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-alpine-linux-musl
Configured with: /home/buildozer/aports/main/gcc/src/gcc-10.3.1_git20211027/configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --build=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl --host=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl --target=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl --with-pkgversion='Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027' --enable-checking=release --disable-fixed-point --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-multilib --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-cloog-backend --enable-languages=c,c++,d,objc,go,fortran,ada --disable-libssp --disable-libmpx --disable-libmudflap --disable-libsanitizer --enable-shared --enable-threads --enable-tls --with-system-zlib --with-linker-hash-style=gnu
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.3.1 20211027 (Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' '/root/cloud/test' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/cc1 -quiet -v /root/cloud/mpi_hello_world.c -quiet -dumpbase mpi_hello_world.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase mpi_hello_world -version -o /tmp/ccdhIMIE.s
GNU C17 (Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027) version 10.3.1 20211027 (x86_64-alpine-linux-musl)
    compiled by GNU C version 10.3.1 20211027, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.22-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/fortify
 /usr/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/include
End of search list.
GNU C17 (Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027) version 10.3.1 20211027 (x86_64-alpine-linux-musl)
    compiled by GNU C version 10.3.1 20211027, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.22-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 3193578801129247e8be66bd6dd0fe05
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' '/root/cloud/test' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccFKfcmE.o /tmp/ccdhIMIE.s
GNU assembler version 2.37 (x86_64-alpine-linux-musl) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.37
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../lib/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' '/root/cloud/test' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/collect2 -plugin /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccmkCMLh.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --eh-frame-hdr --hash-style=gnu -m elf_x86_64 --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 -pie -z relro -z now -o /root/cloud/test /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../lib/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../lib -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../.. /tmp/ccFKfcmE.o -rpath /usr/lib --enable-new-dtags -lmpi -lssp_nonshared -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state -lc -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../lib/crtn.o
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' '/root/cloud/test' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

Also here my `time_out` file:

```
0.030072 0.006682 cc1 -quiet -v /root/cloud/mpi_hello_world.c -quiet -dumpbase mpi_hello_world.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase mpi_hello_world -version -o /tmp/ccdhIMIE.s
0.002234 0.0017 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccFKfcmE.o /tmp/ccdhIMIE.s
0.009905 0.011814 collect2 -plugin /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccmkCMLh.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --eh-frame-hdr --hash-style=gnu -m elf_x86_64 --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 -pie -z relro -z now -o /root/cloud/test /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../lib/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../lib -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../.. /tmp/ccFKfcmE.o -rpath /usr/lib --enable-new-dtags -lmpi -lssp_nonshared -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state -lc -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../lib/crtn.o
```

There doesnt seem to be a problem in the `time_out`, I mean its fast.

Code is from here: [mpi-hello-world/code](https://github.com/mpitutorial/mpitutorial/tree/gh-pages/tutorials/mpi-hello-world/code)

Thank you <3

Edit: Please see the Dockerfile

```
FROM amd64/alpine@sha256:a777c9c66ba177ccfea23f2a216ff6721e78a662cd17019488c417135299cd89 as node

ARG USER=mpiuser
ARG SSH_PATH=/etc/ssh
RUN ping -c 2 8.8.8.8

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    bash \
    build-base \
    libc6-compat \
    openmpi openmpi-dev\
    openssh \
    openrc \
    nfs-utils \
    neovim \
    tini

RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk

#https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_a_nfs-server
#https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_a_SSH_server

RUN adduser -S ${USER} -g "MPI Test User" -s /bin/ash -D ${USER} \
    && echo "${USER} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers \
    && echo ${USER}:* | chpasswd \
    && echo root:* | chpasswd

RUN mkdir ~/.ssh \
    # && rc-update add sshd \
    # && rc-status \
    # touch softlevel because system was initialized without openrc
    && echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> ${SSH_PATH}/sshd_config \
    && echo "PubkeyAuthentication yes" >> ${SSH_PATH}/sshd_config \
    && echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no"  >> ${SSH_PATH}/ssh_config \
    && rm /etc/motd

COPY --chmod=770 ./node_script/helper_node.sh /root/

RUN mkdir ~/cloud

# Using tini - All Tini does is spawn a single child (Tini is meant to be run in a container), and wait for it to exit all the while reaping zombies and performing signal forwarding.
# Docu: https://github.com/krallin/tini

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "-g", "-e 143" ,"-e 137", "--", "/root/helper_node.sh"]
```

And also `/root/helper_node.sh`:

```
# Start sshd i.e. ssh server but gracefully make it shout up
/usr/sbin/sshd -D -d -h /root/.ssh/id_rsa -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Launch with docker-compose: `docker-compose rm -fsv;docker-compose build && docker compose up --scale node=4`

Edit 2 - Reproduce with `mpicc -E; mpicc -S; mpicc -C` (commands omitted due to readability) and we see the same behaviour.

But funny observation `mpicc -v -E [...]` gives:

```
mpicc -v -E -o test.i /root/cloud/mpi_hello_world.c 
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc
Target: x86_64-alpine-linux-musl
Configured with: /home/buildozer/aports/main/gcc/src/gcc-10.3.1_git20211027/configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --build=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl --host=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl --target=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl --with-pkgversion='Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027' --enable-checking=release --disable-fixed-point --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-multilib --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-cloog-backend --enable-languages=c,c++,d,objc,go,fortran,ada --disable-libssp --disable-libmpx --disable-libmudflap --disable-libsanitizer --enable-shared --enable-threads --enable-tls --with-system-zlib --with-linker-hash-style=gnu
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.3.1 20211027 (Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-E' '-o' 'test.i' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/cc1 -E -quiet -v /root/cloud/mpi_hello_world.c -o test.i -mtune=generic -march=x86-64
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/fortify
 /usr/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/include
End of search list.
<------------------ Wait time here -------------------> 
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../lib/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-E' '-o' 'test.i' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

Temporary fix - If I add

```
export COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/


export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../lib/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
```

to `/etc/profile` and `source /etc/profile` everything works as fine as one could wish :)

Comment: what if you simply `gcc -v`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As of https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=mpi-apps: "The Open MPI team strongly recommends that you simply use Open MPI's "wrapper" compilers to compile your MPI application [...]"

Comment: How are you launching the container?  Can you [edit] the question to include the image's Dockerfile?  Where does the `/root/cloud` container directory come from?  (Are you tripping over the problem that host-directory bind mounts can be slow on some platforms?)

Comment: I run with Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.18.1-arch1-1 and I dont know if I am tripping over your mentioned problem. Everything else seems fine and the second compilation of the same unaltered `*.c` file [even if `-o someother_out_file`] is blazingly fast [sub 1 sec]. Will add Dockerfile. Launch instruction in above

Comment: @DavidMaze Do you have an idea how to circumvent your host-dir-bind-mount problem?Tmpfs like so: https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/ ??

Comment: my point is `mpicc -v` ends up invoking `gcc -v`, so it will be interesting to figure out whether the time is spent in the MPI wrapper or in `gcc` itself.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Ah ok. I did what you proposed `gcc -v -time=time_out -o /root/cloud/test /root/cloud/mpi_hello_world.c` and the result is the same, we spend a lot of time waiting in the episode mentiond above, after `[...] End of search list.`. Naturally `gcc` worries about undefined references to MPI stuff

Comment: so you are able to reproduce this issue when Open MPI is out of the picture, right?

Comment: I am able to reproduce when Open MPI is out of the picture.

Comment: So the fix seems to add `COMPILER_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary fix. Add

```
export COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/


export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../lib/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
```

to `/etc/profile` and then `source /etc/profile`.

Everything works as fine as one could wish :)